# What is the value of the constant on the right hand side of Bernoulli equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I've never used that constant in solving problems. In the questions in my book, I just equate $P_1+\frac{1}{2}pv_1^2+pgh_1$ to $P_2+\frac{1}{2}pv_2^2+pgh_2$ to get the unknowns. But what is the value of the constant $P+pgh+\frac{1}{2}pv^2$. Is it a universal constant for ideal fluids or does it depend on something like dimensions of the tube or velocity of the liquid or nature of the liquid,etc?

Comment: I'm just shunting info from one place to another right now, but apparently the constant on the right-hand side of the equation depends only on the streamline chosen. Which mean it will distinguish them, possibly into groups.

Comment: The constant $C$ in Bernouilli's equation $P+\rho g h+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2=C$ for a streamline is a constant of that particular streamline. You shouldn't even really bother with its actual value. What's important is that the left hand side of the equation is constant along the streamline, which allows you to indeed compare two points on it. Essentially Bernouilli's equation is conservation of energy for ideal fluids, so it should not be surprising that the actual value of the constant is inconsequential. Only the fact that it is conserved bears real significance.

Comment: It can perhaps be useful to be even more explicit: $h$ is the height of the point under consideration. But we could choose the zero point of our height measurements wherever we wish. So choosing a different origin already changes the value of $C$. However, regardless of our choice of origin, the quantity $P+\rho g h+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ will be the same for any two points along a given streamline. Note the analogy with gravitational potential energy $U=mgh$, where the choice of zero point for $h$ strongly influences $U$ but has no effect on the significant quantity $\Delta U\equiv U_2-U_1$.

Comment: By the way, if the flow is only horizontal, you can ignore the $h$ terms (potential energy). Also by the way, the equation expresses conservation of momentum, as well as conservation of energy.